# Textfield returns the null values?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

`UITextField` returns the null values, when textfield is empty.

```
NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);

output:   (null)
```

How to get textfield values empty value.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you create the UITextField? By code or is it an IBOutlet?

Comment: @Prine Using IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurred to me as well, it was returning `nil` for `text` property. I placed a check if its null, I assigned empty string, like this:

```
NSString *address = (textField.text && textField.text != NULL)? textField.text:@"";
```

When we look into the header file of `UITextField.h` its `text` property is declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)   NSString *text; // default is nil
```

Which means it can return nil.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to create the connection in the Interface Builder. Select the Storyboard (or Nib file) and select the ViewController. Then connect the textField variable with the UITextField Gui element.

Comment: I did that connection in the interface builder.

Comment: If you select the ViewController in the InterfaceBuilder (Outlet section) there is no "!" sign in front of the textField connection?

Comment: I created an empty project and if the Outlet connection is wrong or not done I get the same behaviour of "(null)" returned. If I create the connection Im receiving a correct "" empty string. Strange..

Answer (score 0):

I think @Prine is right. There must be the problem with the connection in the view controller. Please ensure the connection is done properly for the textField variable, and then you can get the empty value for the "textField.text".